# How to terminate a process that the script starts by command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, shell, command-line

I have a script that receives several arguments. The main thread becomes a server, and the arguments are command line strings that run clients. Once the server has received what it wants from the clients, I want to terminate them. Other than this, I have no control over the clients. They can be written in other languages, they do not need to do any cleanup operations after communication is over, and I need to make sure they terminate.

I tried to make them `threading.Thread`s in which I call `system(run_string)`. However, python does not support killing them directly. So I tried to raise an exception inside using `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc`. For some reason, this only prompts an exception *after* the `system()` call finishes, i.e. after the client terminates itself.

```
>>>main.py
(...)
def raise_exception(t):
    thread_id = get_thread_id(t)
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
        ctypes.c_long(thread_id),
        ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)
    )
    if (res == 0):
        raise ValueError("Invalid thread ID. Cannot terminate.")
    elif (res != 1):
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 0)
        raise SystemError("Bad thing happened. Cannot terminate.")


def f(s):
    try:
        system(s) # subprocess.run(s) yields the same result
    finally:
        print("Terminating.")


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(ttest_s,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    raise_exception(t)
    t.join()
```

```
>>>ttest.py
(...)
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    for i in range(4):
        print(f"{i} second(s) passed.")
        sleep(1)
```

```
>>>python3 main.py
0 second(s) passed.
1 second(s) passed.
2 second(s) passed.
3 second(s) passed.
Terminating.
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threading does not seem to support this particular issue. The following works just fine:

```
t = subprocess.Popen(ttest_s)
time.sleep(1)
t.terminate()
```